# How to search a word in mediawiki api from a particular page?

Tags: mediawiki-api

How to search a word or words in mediawiki api from a particular page onwards?

I tried api.php?action=query&format=xml&titles=Feature_doc&list=search&srsearch=manage

But it searches from all pages instead of "Feature doc" page onwards.

Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by “from a particular page onwards”. Do you mean all pages that are later in alphabetical order than that page? Why would you want that?

Comment: Feature_doc page has different links on it. So I want to search manage word in all those links. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that easily. You would need to get the text of all pages linked from your page using a query like:

api.php?action=query&titles=Feature_doc&generator=links&prop=revisions&rvprop=content

And then manually search the contents for the string.

Comment: Why it does not give all the content of the page Feature_doc? It gives information of some links and skip other links.

Comment: @Hiral Most likely because you're looking only on the first page of results. Add `gpllimit=max` to the query (to increase the size of the page) and look at `query-continue`, if it's present (to get to the next page).

Comment: @Hiral If you're using `generator=links`, then it really should be `gpllimit`. If `gaplimit` works for you, then that suggests you're using `generator=allpages` instead.